# Unable to get Ratings to work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm fairly new to scala and spark but I have alot of experience with Python and other language.
I'm having an odd issue where a function I used with the package org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating

Zepplin notebook stops executing my paragraph when he encoutners this line however I get no error message....

```
val ratings = spark.sql("SELECT _c0 as user,_c1 as product,_c2 as rating FROM datasetframe").rdd.map {case sql.Row(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Int) => Rating(user.toInt, product.toInt, rating.toInt)}
```

I tried to reset Zepplin and start a new code, divide in multiple paragraph.. nothing works.
I'm assuming my line is having a syntax problem however the interpretor is not reporting it.

Anyone can help?!

here is the begining of code:

```
%spark
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating 

val data = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("/user/philippe.samson/testing4/part-m-00000")
data.createOrReplaceTempView("datasetframe")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM datasetframe")

val ratings = spark.sql("SELECT _c0 as user,_c1 as product,_c2 as rating FROM datasetframe").rdd.map {case sql.Row(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Int) => Rating(user.toInt, product.toInt, rating.toInt)}
```

I'm willing to test other approach too.
Let me know !

Comment: New problem, this time the exception is trown by ALS.TRAIN

Comment: The issue I'm getting is this: scala.MatchError: [13468020,117,1] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)....I looked into it and noticed that it has to be a datatype problem, but I cant figure it out... if anyone has insight on match error... let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look okay for the most part, 
With Spark 2 you can try something like this by eliminating extra values there,

```
case class Rating(name:Int, product:Int, rating:Int)

val spark:SparkSession = ???
val df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file")
.map({
case Row(u: Int, p: Int, r:Int) => Rating(u, p, r)
})
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found out that there is an hidden log file on the disk and found the log.... I ended up changning that line to this and it worked :val ratings = spark.sql("SELECT _c0 as user,_c1 as product ,_c2 as rate FROM datasetframe").rdd.map{case Seq(user: Int, product: Int, rate:Double) => Rating(user.toInt, product.toInt, rate. toDouble)}

Answer (score 0):

my problem was related with NaN values down the road.
I got it fixed using this:
predictions.select([to_null(c).alias(c) for c in predictions.columns]).na.drop() 
also I had to import "from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, when, trim"